# Cash On Delivery payment method not showing in checkout page in magento 2

Tags: frontend, payment-methods, magento2.2.2, cash-on-delivery

Cash On delivery payment method not showing in the frontend.

I have enabled the offline payment methods in the backend, It shows all offline payment methods in frontend except COD. Please provide me a solution

[image]

Comment: At the time of enabling method, did you specify any country option?

Comment: No I did not specify

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look on attached screenshot,

Also, Check store view/ website view

Flush cache

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Where i need to check view and website view

Comment: I have configured as you said but still COD not showing

Comment: Go to Store > Configuration :
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3324714/d0345e07444287b6bbc2d035fea3c79e

Comment: Yes I have enabled COD in configuration->sales->configuartion

Comment: See the above post

Comment: Yes, I checked, but have you checked the store views? just change it from store drop-down and check it. :)

Comment: I have only one store view, Can you tell me where the COD is activated in which module  in magento 2